# Username full text search in Meteor.users

Tags: mongodb, meteor, full-text-search, meteor-accounts

I am trying to search the  `meteor.users` collection by username.

I have followed all the steps detailed [here](https://www.okgrow.com/posts/guide-to-full-text-search-in-meteor), but I can't seem to make it work `meteor.users`.

Here is the code I have for that:

On Server  Startup:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.users._ensureIndex({
    "username":"text",
  });
});
```

In my publish function:

```
Meteor.publish("Meteor.users.userSearch",function(searchVal){

  if(!searchVal){
   return Meteor.users.find({});
  }

  return Meteor.users.find({$text:{$search:searchVal}});

});
```

On the client:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  users(){
    var searchValue = Session.get('searchVal');
    Meteor.subscribe('Meteor.users.userSearch',searchValue);
    return Meteor.users.find({});
  }
});
```

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with the above?

When there is no `searchValue`, it works correctly and all the users are returned. As soon as there is any search value, no users are returned at all.

I have also tried directly in the mongodb console `db.users.find({$text:{$search:"some_test"}})`  and again there is no collection object returned.

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. I think the problem is your search value, Mongo searches for words or phrase not character

Comment: have you tried moving your sub outside your helper :

    Template.template.onCreated(function(){
       this.autorun(function(){
          var searchValue = Session.get('searchVal');
          Meteor.subscribe('Meteor.users.userSearch',searchValue);
       })
    })

Comment: @Khang ouuh yes that is the issue thanks for figuring it out!  As soon as I write down a full username it pops up... Would you know of a way to have search by character? (What I am trying to do is have a dynamic search where the ```searchVal``` gets updated with the ```keyup``` event!)

Comment: @MathieuK. yess I had that initially, I thought that this was the issue so I tried moving it into the helper directly!(also was more concise to write for the example)

Comment: I think a normal `find` operation with a Regex search value should be enough

Comment: @Khang Thanks the regex worked! If you want to post your answer formally I will endorse it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do full text search if you just want to search value of only one field (`username` in this case). Using normal `find` command with Regex value as search value is better in this case:

```
Meteor.users.find({
  username: new RegExp('user1', 'gi'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ensureIndex: 
*Deprecated since version 3.0.0*: **db.collection.ensureIndex()** is now an alias for **db.collection.createIndex(**).

_ensureIndex appears to be an orphan.

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.users.createIndex({
    "username":"text"
  });
});
```